# Regex to find all occurences of specific string between two lines

Tags: regex

I would like to search for all occurrences of a specific string between two lines, e.g.

```
some line nobody is interested in
this is the beginning
this is of no interest
attention
not interesting
this is the ending
```

How would a regex look like to find "attention" between "this is the beginning" and "this is the ending"? Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: It would nice if you especify the regex engine you want.

Comment: I would like to include that in a shell script in `bash`

Comment: You're not so clear. You want the matched word be right after the phrase and right before, or just being in the middle of them?

Comment: sorry - I'd like to have them SOMEWHERE in between. No matter where. So all occurrences of "attention" between the starting and ending line.

Answer (score 2):

Try group 1 of this regex:

```
(?s)this is the beginning.*?(attention).*?this is the ending
```

FYI `(?s)` turn on "dot matches newline"

Comment: in patterns.app, this works; unfortunately in my shell script using egrep, it doesn't: `egrep: repetition-operator operand invalid`

Comment: Use the `-P` option with egrep, which activates perl-regexp

Comment: :( seems to be a pretty big deal on OSX: no perl-regex on Mountain Lion there :(

Comment: [\s\S] seems not to work as well...

Answer (score 0):

Exchange `"=="` to whatever pattern you need to match

```
bool foundStart = false;
for line in lines{
    if (line == "this is the beginning")
        foundstart = true;
    else if(line == "this is the ending")
        foundstart = false; //set to false if could come beginning again
        break; //or break directly
    else if (foundstart && line == interestingpattern)
        interesting_lines.Add(line);
}
```

or a regex something like this if you only need one occurance of "interesting":

```
re1='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re2='(start)'   # Word 1   //exchange to your pattern for start
re3='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re4='(interesting)' # Word 2 / Exchange to your pattern for interesting
re5='.*?'   # Non-greedy match on filler
re6='(end)' # Word 3 // exchange to your ending pattern
```

then compile `(re1+re2+re3+re4+re5+re6)` and take out only re4

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var test = "some line nobody is interested in this is the beginning this is of no interest attention not interesting this is the ending";

var testRE = (test.match("this is the beginning (.*) this is the endin"));
alert(testRE[1].match(/attention/g).length);
```